# How can I get iCal url using Google calendar api

Tags: url, rss, google-calendar-api, feed, google-api-php-client

I am successfully able to read/write calendar and events using Google Calendar API. I would like to get an actual private URL to the calendar in the same code. How can I do this?

**Edit:**
I suspect all I need is obtain magicCookie through API, but I do not see that this is possible can anyone confirm if it is or it is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving of magic cookies through the API is not possible.

Comment: what about getting a URL once authenticated?

Comment: That's only possible through the web UI.

Comment: Thank you, that is really to bad as it leaves no easy way for the user to share that link even when access to the calendar is already setup through the app :-( 
Is there any other approach to be able to add calendar feed to native calendar that can be done through API?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "add calendar feed to native calendar". Ideally if you could exactly explain your use case - what your app does, whom to your users share things. There are options of sharing with the API - through ACLs for example.

Comment: Currently within my app I display my own calendar UI (similar to native) that represents Google calendar. This is configured and data is obtained through Google Plus and Google Calendar Service. As part of this I would like to allow the user to add calendar for automatic sync to native device calendar. As such I need iCal URL link - I hope this clarifies what I am trying to achieve.